# Why does view.bringToFront() doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-layout

I got a RelativeLayout on which I have controls in the top. At runtime I want to show a MapView which is just added to the Layout, hiding all other Views under it, but not the controls on top.
Later the MapView is hidden again.

```
layout_main.bringChildToFront(layout_main.findViewWithTag("paramsUI"));
layout_main.invalidate();
```

The findViewByTag thing seems to work, I've checked that in Debug mode.
I also tried:

```
layout_main.findViewWithTag("paramsUI").bringToFront();
```

I there something else I have to do?

Edit: Sorry, the problem is, that the MapView hides the control bar, which should be in top of all views, because of the bringToFront() call.

Comment: What is the problem? That the `MapView` doesn't dissappear? Or that the controls aren't on top of the `MapView`?

Comment: Did you try to create a new `RelativeLayout`? You can add it to the `Main Layout` also and set the controls as you would love.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap your RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout and also put the controls in the LinearLayout. This way whatever you do to the RelativeLayout, the controls will be fine.

Comment: This seems sloppy, but it is the only solution i have yet to come up with that works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a `FrameLayout` rather than a `RelativeLayout`.  A `RelativeLayout` is more for partial views, whereas the `FrameLayout` is optimized for fullscreen applications.  This way, you can control where the items are drawn.

From the [FrameLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the FrameLayout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits). Views that are GONE are used for sizing only if setConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring() is set to true.

I hope this helps!  Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 4.x, you need to call requestLayout() between your two calls:

```
layout_main.bringChildToFront(layout_main.findViewWithTag("paramsUI"));
layout_main.requestLayout();
layout_main.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Seems to work on old and new versions of Android

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) //Lollipop
{
    view.setZ(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < view.getParent().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        if(view != view.getParent().getChildAt(i))
        {
            view.getParent().getChildAt(i).setZ(4);
        }
    }
}

view.bringToFront();
for (int i = 0; i < view.getParent().getChildCount(); i++)
{
    view.getParent().getChildAt(i).invalidate();
}
view.getParent().requestLayout();
view.getParent().invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using `bringtofront()`. It was the parent item used to put the child on the screen. There was a button with property `.isEnabled = true`. After setting the property to `false`, the `view.child.bringtofront()` worked fine.